# MaxLength in Codemirror

Tags: javascript, character, codemirror, maxlength

Hi is there any way to set a maxlength of characters in codemirror v5.5.0. I have tried to do the following:

***Code:***

```
CMUtils.enforceMaxLength = function(cm, change) {
    var maxLength = cm.getOption("maxLength");
    if (maxLength && change.update) {
        var str = change.text.join("\n");
        var delta = str.length-(cm.indexFromPos(change.to) - cm.indexFromPos(change.from));
        if (delta <= 0) { return true; }
        delta = cm.getValue().length+delta-maxLength;
        if (delta > 0) {
            str = str.substr(0, str.length-delta);
            change.update(change.from, change.to, str.split("\n"));
        }
    }
    return true;
}

html_editor.on("beforeChange", CMUtils.enforceMaxLength);
css_editor.on("beforeChange", CMUtils.enforceMaxLength);
js_editor.on("beforeChange", CMUtils.enforceMaxLength);
```

But it doesn't work

P.S I have written maxLength in my code

```
var html_editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("html"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    indentWithTabs: false,
    indentUnit: 2,
    autoCloseTags: true,
    theme: 'dracula',
    maxLenght: 25,
    mode: {
        htmlMode: true,
        name: "xml"
    }
});
```

***UPDATE 1***
My console says that CMUtils isn't defined. How do I define it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with codemirror, but if that's a direct copy/paste you seem to have misspelled `maxLength` in your `html_editor`. Not sure if that'd fix anything - just an observation.

Comment: It still doesn't work

Comment: You've probably already come across the link, but it looks like [someone already solved this on GitHub](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/issues/821#issuecomment-36967065). It might be worth taking a look if you haven't seen it.

Comment: But where should I add the CMUtils? Should I add to my codemirror.js or main.js because it seems that CMUtils need to be defined

Comment: Not being familiar with Codemirror, I don't know where it has to be added. I'd try one and if that doesn't work try the other.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that `CMUtils` is something that [gskinner](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/issues/821#issuecomment-36967065) created for his own work.
There are a few ways to use the function, depending on how you want the function to be scoped.

The way it is currently written can work if the following is added beforehand:

```js
window.CMUtils = window.CMUtils || {};

CMUtils.enforceMaxLength = function(cm, change) { //.....
```

Alternatively, to keep the function private, replace the first line with:

```js
var enforceMaxLength = function(cm, change) {
```

Don't forget to set the option `"maxLength"` on the CodeMirror editor